# WooCommerce Notice Wrapper

Tags: woocommerce, elementor

My shop page back-end is using WooCommerce + elementor.

The cart page is boxed to avoid a messy layout look on larger screens:
[image: cart page]

the top section is stretched to full width:
[image: Heading Section - Stretched]

**Issue:**

The woo notice that appears when you update your cart quantity or remove an item from the cart appears as a boxed view (as it coincides with the width of the "cart" section - which is set to boxed- 1200px)

How can I have "just the woo notice set to full width (no matter the screen size) without needing to make my whole shop page full width?
*I tried to set the wrapper to (width: 100vw), but no luck
[image: ideal full width look]

video sample: https://streamable.com/euksnx

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This looks like an issue with your custom CSS. Do you this site hosted so i can take a look?

Comment: Found the issue I think. Check answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking into your website, I noticed where the issue lays. The `.woocommerce-message` has a width of 100vw. This is why it sticks out of the parent. If you simply remove this, it will show as expected.

If this is styling you didn't apply and can't remove, overwrite it in your child theme with the following class

```
.woocommerce-notices-wrapper .woocommerce-message {
    width: 100%;
}
```

As this is WordPress and sometimes your CSS doesn't want to overwrite, you can always resort to using `!important` for width. However, I think it's better if you try to see if it will work without it.

Image with 100VW what it is now:
[image]

Image with 100% class
[image]

To stretch the banner full width as requested in the comments, add the following CSS:

```
.woocommerce-notices-wrapper .woocommerce-message {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: hello again - i changed it to 100% and still seeing the issue for screens 1201px and up. (for example a screen that has 1440 px width it looks bad)

Comment: I don't see it, I tested it on every possible responsive view and it stays nicely centered on the right spot at 1440 1201

Comment: alright ill see what I can do

Comment: Added it to the answer