# WooCommerce email templates - Remove {site_title} from email body

Tags: woocommerce

Hello – recently my email template sent to customers once they place an order are including the site title outside the main email body.

- this is a WooCommerce store.

I haven’t made any changes recently that I can recall, and tried deleting the copied email template from my server and just use the original but the issue persists.

Any Advise on how to remove it?

Please see screenshot link:
https://ibb.co/K7DM3jV

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would recommend using this plugin to preview your template - https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-preview-emails/ there you may find more answers why its happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the content of your WooCommerce emails, you can do so by editing the templates. You can access the templates by going to WooCommerce > Settings > Emails. From there, you can select the template you want to edit and make your changes.

[image]

If that doesn't get you your disired result you can also overwrite the woocommerce email template by copying the template to your child theme.

Copy the following file from:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-header.php
```

To

```
wp-content/themes/my-theme-directory/woocommerce/emails/email-header.php
```

Then remove the `{site_title}` from there and you should be fine.

Let me know if this solved your issue, if not, I will look into it further.

Comment: I added a copy of the template to my child them but i do not see where i can remove the {site_title} from showing up on the "body" of the email.

Comment: Do you use default emails by woo or do you use a plugin to create the formatted email

Comment: thank you - maybe you know a solution to my other issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74285812/woocommerce-notice-wrapper